# How to fetch Image from the express API and mongo DB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image, api, express

My api is having the quoteImage key contains the path of the image stored in the backend.
[API image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3cLS.png)

now i want to display this in my react application.I am able to display title and description but not the images.kindly help

[react appliation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMyuc.png)

Comment: edit the post and add the react code of the section where the image is being loaded

Answer (score 1):

## The Fix

You'll have to make express server the images as static files jf you are saving the image locally

(which you should avoid in production as they might be deleted on redeployments).

To do this, assuming the images are present in `public/images`, you should add the following lines

```js
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Then, `public/images/1.png` should be available at http://localhost:8000/images/1.png

## Why is this needed?

Essential, express just serves the responses you generate in routes by default. So you need to ask express to serve the files inside "public" as static files (which are served as is).

**NOTE** - Express looks up the files relative to the static directory, so the name of the static directory is not part of the URL.

## Reference

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: I am not able to get the image  http://localhost:8000/images/1.png by applying this method also

Comment: at what port id your server running? Because the port in the image url has to be the server port not react